# Desktop app does not launch when running test on Jenkins

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, sikuli

I am testing a desktop app using Sikuli in Java on Windows. For now, my code is simple. I am just testing if the app launches. Please see below the line of code I’m using to launch the app.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(appPath);
```

When I test it on IntelliJ, the app launches fine. However, when I run the same test on Jenkins, the code does not fail but the app doesn’t launch at all. Could anyone please assist. Thanks. [image: This is how I build my test on Jenkins. It’s a maven project.]

Answer (score 0):

You must provide much more details about your setup. Here are some tips:

- can you successfully run the test form command line on your machine
- can you successfully run the test form command line on your Jenkins agent machine
- what is logged in jenkins job log for this run ( consider adding pure prints to your script for debuging purposes)
- does agent machine has real UI and does agent runs in real UI